# Exception Type: ValidationError at /home Exception Value: [u"'1a3288b3-7588-483f-8e85-1affa952dbbf' value must be an integer."]

Tags: django, django-models

I have created registration page , model for it and when user gets registered he gets redirected to home page. When i click on register user is getting inserted in database but when it redirects to home page i am getting this error:

Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\KR\Desktop\projects\project2\welcome\homeview.py" in home
  14.     if request.user.is_authenticated():

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  234.             self._setup()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in _setup
  380.         self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py" in 
  24.         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py" in get_user
  12.         request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth__init__.py" in get_user
  180.         user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth__init__.py" in _get_user_session_key
  59.     return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py" in to_python
  927.                 params={'value': value},

Exception Type: ValidationError at /home
Exception Value: [u"'1a3288b3-7588-483f-8e85-1affa952dbbf' value must be an integer."]

This is the model:

```
class user_model(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="None")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="None")
    email = models.EmailField(default="None")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="abc123")

    '''Custom user information fields. '''
    myself = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="None")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="None")
    mobilePh = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="None")
    workPh = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="None")
    workEmail = models.EmailField(default="None")
    last_login = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="None")
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(width_field=None, height_field=None,
                                    blank=True, default="None",
                                    upload_to=upload_profile_pic)
    banner_pic = models.ImageField(width_field=None, height_field=None,
                                   blank=True, default="None",
                                   upload_to=upload_banner_pic)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_id']

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_model'
        app_label = 'welcome'
```

This is the register view

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    if validate_registration_attributes(request.POST):
        user_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        try:
        user = User.objects.create(user_id=str(user_uuid),                                                                     last_login=str(datetime.datetime.now()),
                       username=request.POST['username'],
                       first_name=request.POST['first_name'],
                       last_name=request.POST['last_name'],
                       email=request.POST['email'],
                       profile_pic="blank_image.png",
                       banner_pic="blank_image.png",
                       password='',
                       )
        user.set_password(request.POST['passwd_1'])
        user.save()

        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
        except Exception as err:
        user.delete()
        print "Something happened"
        raise Exception("""EXCEPTION at register-user.objects.create in
                        userObject:%s""" % (err))
        global exceptmsg
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/welcome')
    else:
        print "New account registration form validation failed"
        context = {'RegisterResponse': exceptmsg}
        return render(request, 'welcome.html', context)
```

This is the home view:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
    else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/welcome')
```

Is it the problem with the model or anything else. Please help.

Comment: can you try to save the user_id as integear like user_id=123456 , just try

Answer (score 0):

I had forgot to override the default user model in settings.py. I changed the value of AUTH_USER_MODEL to  **myappname.user_model**. Now it works fine.